# How to make SQL query that outputs records that appear more than once and to include the duplicate records in the results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am a new SQL programmer, and I have been trying to figure out how to write a SQL query that shows when addresses are duplicates in 4 separate attributes and outputs all of the duplicate records. I have written the following query, but it appears to only show one of the duplicate records but not all of them.

```
SELECT 
apvenfil_sql.vend_no,
apvenfil_sql.vend_name,
apvenfil_sql.sort_name,
apvenfil_sql.addr_1,
apvenfil_sql.addr_2,
apvenfil_sql.city,
apvenfil_sql.state,
apvenfil_sql.zip,
apvenfil_sql.country,
apvenfil_sql.contact,
apvenfil_sql.acct_dt,
apvenfil_sql.last_active_dt,
apvenfil_sql.ap_terms_cd,
apvenfil_sql.cus_no,
apvenfil_sql.purch_ytd,
apvenfil_sql.purch_last_yr,
apvenfil_sql.amt_pd_ytd,
apvenfil_sql.amt_pd_last_yr,
apvenfil_sql.balance,
apvenfil_sql.lst_chk_dt,
apvenfil_sql.last_chk_amt,
apvenfil_sql.chk_no,
apvenfil_sql.payee_name,
apvenfil_sql.A4GLIdentity,
apaltadr_sql.vend_no,
apaltadr_sql.vend_alt_adr_cd,
apaltadr_sql.vend_name,
apaltadr_sql.addr_1,
apaltadr_sql.addr_2,
apaltadr_sql.city,
apaltadr_sql.state,
apaltadr_sql.zip,
apaltadr_sql.country,
apaltadr_sql.A4GLIdentity
FROM
apvenfil_sql
LEFT JOIN apaltadr_sql
    ON apaltadr_sql.vend_no = apvenfil_sql.vend_no 
WHERE 
apvenfil_sql.addr_1 IN
    (     SELECT addr_1 
          FROM apvenfil_sql
          GROUP BY addr_1
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) OR
apvenfil_sql.addr_2 IN
    (     SELECT addr_2 
          FROM apvenfil_sql
          GROUP BY addr_2
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) OR
apaltadr_sql.addr_1 IN 
    (     SELECT addr_1 
          FROM apaltadr_sql
          GROUP BY addr_1
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) OR
apaltadr_sql.addr_2 IN 
    (     SELECT addr_2 
          FROM apaltadr_sql
          GROUP BY addr_2
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) 
ORDER BY 
apvenfil_sql.vend_no;
```

For reference, the SQL Server version is 2000.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Could you include an example of what you are expecting?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query.   Probably your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Tab Alleman, I ran some more queries on that data and tested some of the data in excel, and you're right, I was expecting a larger output of duplicates. I must have used a full join or something in the past by accident to be expecting more duplicates. Thank you!